# Wix: How can I have a custom user profile page with a rich text field?

Tags: javascript, velo

In my Wix (website builder) website I am wanting to have each user have their own profile page with a textarea to enter their life story.

I have a Wix Members Area, and I have the default MEMBERS page that displays all users.  Clicking on a user brings up the default Profile page and if the chosen user is the current user, then an "Edit Profile" button is displayed. This is all perfect with one exception.

The data that backs the Profile page is the member data that resides in the Members - PublicData collection.  I can add a column to that collection.  However, I cannot add a column of Rich Text data type, and the standard Text data type only contains a maximum of about 150 characters, whereas I need to store 1000+ characters for the user's life story, and it would be nice to allow the user to embed a link.

If have been experimenting with a Custom Collection and the Dynamic List and Item (user) pages.  When a list item is clicked on the Item page comes up.  But I need the Item page to be editable IF the user is *the current user*.  Do I need to make a third Dynamic page that is displayed for the current user?  If so, how do I check for that?  OR is there a way to do this in Javascript by setting the dataset mode and permissions?